# Fetch request failing due to CORS missing token in Firefox

Tags: java, spring, cors

When trying to issue a POST request in firefox the following error messages come up:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.net/graphql. (Reason: missing token 'content-type' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.net/graphql. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

The same request succeeds in Chrome. The request I am sending is:

````
method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    'x-client-id': '123',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: "query ..."
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(console.log);```

I am issuing this request while on another https origin.

My setup in my code for cors is simply the spring annotation:
```@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = {"content-type", "x-client-id"})```
````

Comment: Try clearing your Firefox browser cache for the site, or force reloading

Answer (score -1):

You will need these headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://api.bob.com
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header Content-Type: text/html;
>
> charset=utf-8

at the target in order to allow CORS. If you have no access to the remote stuff, then use your server as a proxy and send the request from there, return the response to your browser.